# How to save data permanently untill uninstallation of app in simulator or iphone in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3

Here i need to save a token generated from json and need to save in app data until the app is removed from simulator or iphone how to implement this can anyone help me ?

Comment: You can use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: If this is a unique token for login, it should not be saved in UserDefaults because it's not secure. It should be stored in the KeyChain instead.

Comment: it should save untill the app has uninstalled from simulator or iphone if not it should be there @Moritz

Comment: As described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

**Note:**  Transferred apps lose their keychain access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to store data is in [`UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

You can store and retrieve data from userDefault like

For Save data in `UserDefaults`

```
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "user_token")
```

For retrieve  data in `UserDefaults`

```
print("\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "user_token"))")
```

As per **@vadian**'s suggestion,

UserDefaults have many methods. To save and retrieve data here, we used `value:forKey`, similarly if the value is a string then `string:forKey` and Etc. that are deprecated.

But, here is the best way `set(_: forKey:)` read **@vadian's** comment.

Comment: **Do not** suggest `valueForKey: / setValue:forKey` with `UserDefaults`. The dedicated methods are `object(forKey` or even `string(forKey` and the generic `set(_ : forKey`

Comment: It will save the values permanently or deletes after closing the app ? @ArpitJain

Comment: Your data will be saved permanently. It will be deleted after kill you app from your device or simulator or you manually remove by the code otherwise it will not be  removed.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a token, use `UserDefaults`:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "jsonToken")
```

retrieve the value later using:

```
if let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "jsonToken") {
    // use the token
} else {
    // no token was yet saved
}
```

Comment: **Do not** suggest `valueForKey: / setValue:forKey` with `UserDefaults`. The dedicated methods are `object(forKey` or even `string(forKey` and the generic `set(_ : forKey`

Answer (score 0):

If the information is important Userdefaults is not the right place for storing information, it doesn't matter if its just a string or an object ...

Use Keychain for that, here you can find some example: 
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/securing-user-data-with-keychain-for-ios-e720e0f9a8e2

The security of your customers is the most important think.

Answer (score 0):

Data in keychain will stay even if application is uninstalled so you have several other options to choose:

1. UserDefaults (easiest)
2. Save to file (text file)
3. SQLite database (still text file)
4. CoreData (database applying SQLCipher you will get it more secure)

All above with exception of CoreData + SQLCipher are considered unsecure.
Optionally you may use some technique to encrypt before saving and decrypt after reading your token from data container...